# R: find sum of every i < j without using for loop

Tags: r, sum

How to find sum of i<j (i,j = 1 to 25) of i without using for loop in R language.
[image]

This equation is what I am trying to code exactly, I need to get the index of both i and j and calculate sum of determination from there.

[image]

{(x_i, j_i)}i = 1 to 25

Answer (score 1):

We can use `outer`

```
sum(outer(i, j, FUN = `<`))
```

If we need to find the `sum` of 'x'

```
sum(matrix(x, 25, 25)[outer(x, x, FUN = `<`)])
```

#### data

```
i <- 1:25
j <- 1:25
x <- rnorm(25)
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. I've updated the questions, is there a way to use outer and perform the above equation?

Answer (score 0):

For vector `x`, you can try the code below

```
sum(cumsum(x)[-length(x)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# DATA
set.seed(42)
n = 25
v = 1:n
x = rnorm(n)

sum(rep(v, n) < rep(v, each = n))
sum(rep(x, n)[rep(v, n) < rep(v, each = n)])
```